# Saber la consulta SQL que se esta ejecutando con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

lanzo una consulta SQL en una web PHP mediante mysql y PDO. la pregunta es ¿como puedo imprimir por pantalla o ver de algún modo la consulta que se esta ejecutando?. La consulta la hago mediante prepare y execute para pasarle los parámetros, de esta manera

```
    public function exists($username){
        try{
            $query = $this->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
            $query->execute([
                'username' => $username
            ]);
          
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

La clase model que tiene la función prepare

```
class Model{


    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database();

        
    }

    function query($query){
        return $this->db->connect()->query($query);
    }

    
    function prepare($query){
        return $this->db->connect()->prepare($query);
    }


}
```

Y la conexion a la BD

```
class Database{

    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $charset;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host = constant('HOST');
        $this->db = constant('DB');
        $this->user = constant('USER');
        $this->password = constant('PASSWORD');
        $this->charset = constant('CHARSET');
    }

    function connect(){
        try{
            $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];
            
            $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
            error_log('Conexión a BD exitosa');
            return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            error_log('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

¿Cómo podría de algún modo ver la consulta SQL que se esta ejecutando? GRACIAS!!

Comment: intentaste con var_dump($query);???

Comment: Prueba con `$query->queryString`

Comment: var_dump($query); no me saca nada y $query->queryString me saca el literal sin las variables q le paso en el execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución encontrada, en el archivo de configuración de mySQL (mi.cnf o mi.ini) añadir estas líneas.

```
[mysqld]
general_log=1
general_log_file="C:/log/sql.log"
```

Sustituimos C:/log/sql.log por la ruta donde quieras almacenar el log, ahí se almacenaran
todas las consultas SQL incluidas las parametrizadas con el valor de las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a sugerir cambiar la clase `Database`, extendiendo a PDO y aplicando el patrón [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), para que todos los modelos usen la misma conexión a base de datos que, aparte de permitirte agrupar todas las sentencias ejecutadas, también ayuda a optimizar recursos.

```
class Database extends PDO {
    // Definir instancia para usar solamente una
    private static $_instance = null;

    // Acumular todas las sentencias ejecutadas
    public $queries = [];

    // El método debe ser estático
    public static function connect() {
        // Todavía no se ha establecido la conexión
        if(self::$_instance === null) {
            $host = constant('HOST');
            $db = constant('DB');
            $user = constant('USER');
            $password = constant('PASSWORD');
            $charset = constant('CHARSET');
            try {
                $connection = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
                $options = [
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                ];
                // Crear instancia
                self::$_instance = new self($connection, $user, $password, $options);
                // Para tener registro de consultas ejecutadas, extender PDOStatement
                self::$_instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['DbStatement', [self::$_instance]]);

                error_log('Conexión a BD exitosa');
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                error_log('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    // Ejecutar una consulta directamente
    public function query($query) {
        // Agregar consulta a lista
        $this->queries[] = [
            'consulta' => $query,
            'params' => []
        ];
        // Ejecutar y devolver
        return parent::query($query);
    }
    // Mostrar las sentencias ejecutadas
    public function getQueries() {
        $total = count($this->queries);
        $msg = "<p>Consultas ejecutadas: $total</p>";
        if($total > 0) {
            // Crear una lista ordenada con consultas y parámetros
            $msg .= '<ul>';
            foreach($this->queries as $query) {
                $msg .= "<li>Consulta: {$query['consulta']}<br>Parámetros: ";
                if(count($query['params']) == 0) {
                    $msg .= '(Sin parámetros)';
                } else {
                    // ¿No se usan marcas ? para los campos?
                    if(mb_strpos($query['consulta'], '?') === false) {
                        // Agregar campos :campo1, :campo2, ... :campoX
                        $msg .= implode(', ', array_keys($query['params']));
                        $msg .= '<br>Valores: ';
                    }
                    // Agregar valores
                    $msg .= implode(', ', array_values($query['params']));
                }
                $msg .= '</li>';
            }
            $msg .= '<ul>';
        }
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

Ahora, necesitas la clase que extiende `PDOStatement` para agregar cada consulta a la lista y puedes tenerla dentro del mismo archivo PHP de la clase anterior

```
class DbStatement extends PDOStatement {
    protected $_db = false;
    // Solo se obtiene la clase de base de datos para actualizar lista de consultas
    protected function __construct($db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
    // Actualizar lista de consultas y ejecutar
    public function execute($args = null) {
        // Asegurar que $args sea un arreglo
        ($args === null && $args = []);
        $this->_db->queries[] = [
            'consulta' => $this->queryString,
            'params' => $args
        ];
        // Si quieres aquí mismo puedes mostrar la consulta
        // Pero no es recomendable, es mejor hacerlo al final del script
        return parent::execute($args);
    }
}
```

### ¿Cómo se usa?

Siempre que necesites acceso a base de datos vas a obtener la conexión con una llamada al método estático `connect()`:

```
class Model {
    // Definir las propiedades que vas a usar
    private $db;
    function __construct() {
        // Conectar a base de datos, no debes usar new Database()
        // Solo ejecuta el método estático
        $this->db = Database::conect();
    }

    function query($query) {
        // No necesitas ->conect(), porque la conexión ya se estableció
        return $this->db->query($query);
    }
    
    function prepare($query){
        return $this->db->prepare($query);
    }
}
```

No hay modificaciones al ejecutar consultas:

```
public function exists($username) {
    try {
        $query = $this->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $query->execute([
            'username' => $username
        ]);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Al terminar tu script simplemente obtienes todas las consultas y se recomienda que lo hagas solo en etapa de desarrollo, **nunca en producción**, a menos que el rol de usuario sea administrador.

```
echo Database::connect()->getQueries();
```

**Ventajas:**

- Usas solo una conexión a base de datos para todo el script; actualmente parece que cada que ejecutas una consulta creas una nueva conexión y esto podría traer problemas cuando la cantidad de usuarios concurrentes en tu sitio se incremente, apareciendo mensajes de error acerca de conexiones no disponibles
- Todas las consultas se van a agregar a un arreglo y puedes mostrarlas fácilmente

**Desventajas:**

- Seguramente vas a tener que realizar muchas modificaciones en tu proyecto para usar esta propuesta

Answer (score 0):

PECL/mysqlnd_uh provee de un mecanismo para poder monitorear de manera sencilla las consultas que se realizan a la base de datos. Para ello, puedes valerte de las funciones *[mysqlnd_uh_set_connection_proxy()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqlnd-uh-set-connection-proxy.php)* y *[mysqlnd_uh_set_statement_proxy()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqlnd-uh-set-statement-proxy.php%60)* que instalan *proxies* de conexión y de sentencias preparadas.

El primero debería derivar de `MysqlndUhConnection::query()` y el segundo de `MysqlndUhPreparedStatement::prepare()`.

Al final, sin importar la extensión que utilices, siempre que haya sido compilada para utilizar [mysqlnd](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php), que es el control nativo estándar para mySQL, todas las consultas de una base de datos que no utilicen sentencias preparadas nativas llamarán al proxy de conexión y todas las que utilicen sentencias preparadas llamarán al proxy de sentencias preparadas.

Si combinamos estas funciones con *[debug_print_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-print-backtrace.php)*, tenemos una herramienta de monitoreo de SQL en 20 líneas de código:

```
<?php
class conn_proxy extends MysqlndUhConnection {
 public function query($res, $query) {
  debug_print_backtrace();
  return parent::query($res, $query);
 }
}
class stmt_proxy extends MysqlndUhPreparedStatement {
 public function prepare($res, $query) {
  debug_print_backtrace();
  return parent::prepare($res, $query);
 }
}
mysqlnd_uh_set_connection_proxy(new conn_proxy());
mysqlnd_uh_set_statement_proxy(new stmt_proxy());

printf("Delegados instalados...\n");
?>
```

Esto va a producir salidas como la siguiente:

```
#0  conn_proxy->query(Resource id #19, SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username)
#1  PDO->query(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username) called at [example.php:19]
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(1) "juan"
  }
}
#0  stmt_proxy->prepare(Resource id #753, SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username)
#1  mysqli->prepare(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username) called at [example.php:22]
```

Para que esto funcione, debes asegurarte que *[mysqlnd-uh.enable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqlnd-uh.configuration.php#ini.mysqlnd-uh.enable)* sea `true`. Cuando este parámetro está en `false` los proxies no pueden instalarse.

La principal ventaja de este enfoque es que solo tienes que asegurarte de incluir este archivo mientras desarrollas tu sitio y, sin ningún cambio sobre tu código, tienes acceso a todas las sentencias SQL que se ejecutan. No olvides quitar el/los `include`/`include once` del archivo antes de poner en producción el sitio.